# Why does restoring Eclipse / Content Assist defaults not persist when Eclipse is closed and later re-opened?

Tags: eclipse, default, content-assist

Working environment: Windows 10, Eclipse 2019-06 (v. 4.12.0)

A couple months ago I changed some of the settings at Window>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced. After a few weeks I realized that the default settings worked better than my changes, so I clicked the ‘Restore defaults’ button and everything worked fine … so long as I never closed Eclipse. If I closed Eclipse (for example, yesterday) and opened it again (today), the settings do ..NOT.. reflect the defaults, but something else which I presume to be the changes I made.

I’ve been trying to solve this for the last month and nothing works. This ..SHOULD.. be a simple, straight forward process where clicking the ‘Restore defaults’ button does ..EXACTLY.. that, and that Eclipse remembers that action; but it doesn’t.

Any ideas on what I need to do in order to reset Content Assist to its default settings so that I don’t have to go through the tedious process of Window>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced>Restore defaults every time I open Eclipse?

Comment: Is in _Window > Preferences: Oomph > Setup Tasks > Preference Recorder_ and in _... > Preference Synchronizer_ something enabled?

Comment: @howlger - Thanks for responding. For the first 'chain' (Window> ... Preference Recorder) the 'Record into' checkbox is NOT ticked, but in the (long) list underneath (which is disabled unless 'Record into' is ticked) there are maybe 20-30 items that are checked. Near the top there are 10 items that refer to 'xxx.eclipse.jdt.core.codeComplete.xxx', and near the bottom 6 refer to'xxx.eclipse.jdt.ui.content_assist_xxx' [where xxx is my wild card :)].The 'Synchronize with Eclipse' check box on the 'Preference Synchronizer' page is NOT ticked and there is nothing else there. Is this a start?

Comment: By default, non items are checked. Does in _Window > Preferences: Oomph > Setup Tasks_ enable __Skip automatic task execution on startup time_ fix your issue?

Comment: @howlger - Thanks for the tip, it may be better than my solution. Late Friday I unchecked all the 'content_assist' items (near the bottom of the list). That seems to solve the problem, but it also seems heavy-handed. Your tip may be more nuanced and I'll give it a try for a week or so before checking back here. About Oomph, the idea is brilliant as are many Eclipse features, but the implementation isn't easy to understand, which in truth is as much my problem as Eclipse's. This is my first hand-on experience with Oomph, and like most things the more practice you get, the better you become. Thx

Comment: @howlger - If you can tell me how to give you credit for the answer I'll do what's needed on my end.

Answer (score 2):

The restoring of the previous preferences might cause by the ***Oomph Preference Recorder*** which can be used to share preferences between workspaces, installations and even computers.

By default, recording and synchronizing of preferences are disabled:

- ***Window > Preferences: Oomph > Setup Tasks > Preference Recorder***
- ***Window > Preferences: Oomph > Setup Tasks > Preference Synchronizer***

Oomph can also be used [to configure the IDE by running so called **setup tasks**](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring) which also might set preferences. In ***Window > Preferences: Oomph > Setup Tasks*** this can be turned off by checking the checkbox ***Skip automatic task execution on startup time***.

  -

Comment: Excellent, and thanks for the help. FWIW I'm going to check out your YouTube stuff later this week.

Answer (score 0):

You can also capture the current state of any preference.

Use Navigate -> Open Setup -> User and click on the "Capture Preferences" toolbar button.

This shows all instance scoped preferences and you can selectively choose which ones you want to capture as a preference task in the user.setup. Then you should be able to synchronize those with your account as well.
Oomph plugin

Comment: thanks for your comment, this sounds like it may be a better solution. Hopefully I'll be able to check it out in the next few days.